# Checking if input is in a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
x = input()
if x in numbers:
    print("Hey you did it")
else:
    print("Nope")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but it always tells me that my number is not in the list.. even though it is. Works fine with strings, though.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: python 3 or python 2?

Comment: Your code works in Python 2, I just tested.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.1

Comment: What are you typing in?

Comment: This is only an issue with Python 3 for people who are running 2.7 and are not having this issue. Python 3 requires an explicit cast of `int(x)`, as seen in Dan's answer.

Comment: If it was Python 2, wouldn't it need to say raw_input, not just input? Also, the print statements were given as functions. Given these two "clues", it seemed safe to me to assume this is Python 3 (which turned out to be right).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input is a string, so you are comparing strings to integers. First convert to an int then do the membership test:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
x = input()
if int(x) in numbers:
    print("Hey you did it")
else:
    print("Nope")
```

To make this slightly more robust, you should handle the `ValueError` that will occur if the user does not input an integer (there's always one user who will enter 'cheeseburger' instead of a number):

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
x = input()
try:
    i = int(x)
    if i in numbers:
        print("Hey you did it")
    else:
        print("Nope")
except ValueError:
    print("You did not enter a number")
```

Comment: @Mothrakk glad to hear that. If this solves your problem completely, please mark it as the accepted answer so that other users know that the issue has been solved.

Comment: To be honest, the `[duplicate]` tag already lets other users know that the issue has been solved (this is a very common question, too).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 10-4, didn't realize it was a dup (but should have known). Thanks.